# linq in plain english

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone explain in plain english the syntax of this:

Here is the signature of the `OrderBy` operator:

> ```
> OrderedSequence<TElement> OrderBy<TElement, TKey>(
>     this IEnumerable<TElement> source, 
>     Func<TElement, TKey> keySelector
> )
> ```

This shows that the type of the delegate you need to provide to `OrderBy` is `Func<TElement, TKey>`.

I'm looking to build a function that receives a list and a string as a parameter (the column name) and I'm stuck on the syntax of the `OrderBy` extension method. What does `Func<...>` mean? Where do I put the string parameter to sort with?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `source` a `DataSet`, a `List`?

Comment: It's the result of a linq query, a list of objects: List<MyObjectModel>

Comment: And do you know which property a priori that you want to sort? Or is the property name a variable? If it is known, @Donblas has your answer. If not you'll need something slightly more involved.

Comment: No, I don't; it's for a gridview sorting so the input is a string called TheColumn that comes from the gridview sorting event handler:    protected void GridCallHistorySort(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {

     var TheColumn = (e.SortExpression).ToString();

Comment: How do <T> work? Can a sort function accept any list and sort it according to a string? Is this where generic types come into play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you might see it in practice, given

```
List<MyClass> list;
```

and

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

you might say

```
list.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

The `this IEnumerable<TElement> source` is how we know that we call this as an extension method off of any IEnumerable.

If you're using a dynamic property name, you're going to have to get more fancy. I'd first define a helper function to make sure our lambda doesn't get too messy. Note that for the sake of time and clarity to the concept being demonstrated, I've omitted some things like checks and error handling:

```
public object GetPropertyByName(object obj, string propertyName)
{
    object result = null;

    var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    result = prop.GetValue(obj, null);

    return result;

}
```

Now use our helper as follows:

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
list.Add(new MyClass { Name = "John" });
list.Add(new MyClass { Name = "David" });
list.Add(new MyClass { Name = "Adam" });
list.Add(new MyClass { Name = "Barry" });

const string desiredProperty = "Name"; // You can pass this in
var result = list.OrderBy(x => GetPropertyByName(x, desiredProperty));
foreach (MyClass c in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
}
```

Comment: Initially my sort order is a string. If I understand correctly, you pass the string to GetPropertyByName so that you return result, which seems to be the sort parameter the lambda will sort with. Of what type is the variable result?

Comment: GetPropertyByName will return the value of the property defined by propertyName as it is set on the given obj. Given a MyClass object as obj parameters and "Name" as the propertyName parameter, the result will be David, Adam, etc.

Comment: When you say "will return the VALUE of the property defined by its name", what do you mean by value? I pass in the name of the column via a string and it return the name of the column in a type that's understandable by linq, is that it?

Comment: I mean that if you're using MyClass objects and you pass in "Name," it will return something like "David" or "Adam". LINQ isn't looking for a column name here, it's looking for a way to map the elements of the enumeration to the value that should be used for the sort operation. I hope this explains it better.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, this guy is an extension method (from the this) that works on an IEnumerable of some thing (TElement). It takes a method that when given an element in the list, returns something you can sort by.

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx

```
        class Pet
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
        }

        public static void OrderByEx1()
        {
            Pet[] pets = { new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8 },
                           new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4 },
                           new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=1 } };

            IEnumerable<Pet> query = pets.OrderBy(pet => pet.Age);

            foreach (Pet pet in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", pet.Name, pet.Age);
            }
        }

        /*
         This code produces the following output:

         Whiskers - 1
         Boots - 4
         Barley - 8
        */
```

Comment: Yea but I want to return the list sorted by a string as parameter. Here it's sorted by pet.Age but instead of that, I'd like to order it by "Age" (the string) and then have the function determine that the sort order is by Age (the column name). That way, I can have the sorter work for any class (here it's just Pet) and take any string as parameter.

Comment: Then use the version that takes a "IComparer<TKey> comparer"

Answer (score 1):

`Func<TElement, TKey>` refers to a function that takes an argument of type `TElement` and returns a value of type `TKey`. You could specify the types when calling the function (e.g. `foo.OrderBy<MyObject, string>(...)`), but the compiler can usually infer them from the supplied function.

Now, `OrderBy` doesn't take a column name to sort by, it takes a function that takes the object to inspect as an argument and returns to the value to sort by. For example,

```
list.OrderBy(item => item.SortByField)
```

Of course, the function could be defined using something else besides lambda syntax (as a normal method for instance), but this is usually most convenient.

In order to sort by a runtime-defined property name, you'll have to come up with a way to make a function that extracts a value from the specified property. One way is to use reflection, another way would be to use the `Expression` class to construct a lambda expression on the fly and then compile it into a `Func`.

Here's an example (completely untested - but something along these lines)

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public static IEnumerable<TValue> OrderByField<TValue>(this IEnumerable<TValue> source, string fieldName) {
    PropertyDescriptor desc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(TValue))[fieldName];
    return source.OrderBy(item => desc.GetValue(item));
}
```

Comment: In this case, if TKey is the column to be sorted by, does this mean I have to first right a function that returns the "name" of the column based on a string so that I can put it in TKey?

Comment: TKey is the type of the value to be sorted by.

Comment: @frenchie: No, it's a type parameter.

Comment: Is it the type of the data in the column?

Comment: @frenchie: Seeing that this has nothing to do with tables, "column" might not be the right word. It is the type of value based on which the data is to be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

U can use

```
(from o in listOfObjects
select o).OrderBy(p => p.columnname)
```

Here **columnname** is the column on which you want to do **order by**

Comment: @Matti - It could be also like `(from o in listOfObjects where o.Gender=="Male" select o)`  or some thing more complex query