# Most efficient way to compare lots variables? C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting a datatable with customer data from a MySql databaes and a customer object from a web service.

I want to compare every value in the datatable with the values in the object and if there is one field that differs I want to perfrom some tasks.

I know I can get the values from the datatable with:

```
string mCompanyName = row["Company Name"].ToString();
string mCreatedDate = row["Created Date"].Tostring();
//etc..
```

Then I get the values from the web service

```
string wsCompanyName = customer.companyName;
string wsCreatedDate = customer.createdDate;
```

There are about 50 fields and doing

```
if( mCompanyName != wsCompanyName & mCreatedDate != wsCreatedDate and so on..) (or similar)
{
    //Do something
}
```

seems to be a bit tedious and not very nice so how should I perform this? Is there a much better way to chuck it into a list and use some fancy LINQ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put them in a Dictionary and search that way:

```
Dictionary<string, string> mData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

mData.Add("Company Name", row["Company Name"].ToString());


Dictionary<string, string> wsData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

wsData.Add("Company Name", customer.CompanyName);
```

Then loop through:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in mData)
{
    if (wsData[pair.Key] == pair.Value) 
    { 
        // Do something
    }
}
```

This way, for every entry in mData (the data from your database), it will look for an entry in wsData with the same name.

I wouldn't create individual variables for each piece of data. It would be difficult to maintain, and would not scale well (lots of copy and pastes).

Comment: Thanks for that mfanto, just a question though, this works well for one type but what would I do if some values are int, some dates, some double and so on?

Comment: @Nick then `Dictionary<string,object>` and use `object.Equals`. However, this can lead to other problems, such as `"1".Equals(1) -> false` and so the "safer" solution *may* be to have them all converted into strings (however is appropriate) first or add in a crude check on the type (`a.GetType() == b.GetType`) and perhaps fail-fast if it doesn't align.

Answer (score 2):

For cases like this I sometimes put them ("the objects") in something IEnumerable (make sure to "line them up") and use the [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) extension method. It performs standard `Equals()`'ity and is "cheap enough for my usage".

For instance:

```
var equal = (new object[] { row["A"], row["B"] })
    .SequenceEqual(new object[] { x.A, x.B });
```

This requires LINQ, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you, but it needs to modify this to use in your scenerio [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880814/linq-in-plain-english/)